# How to convert array of string to array of integer

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm trying to learn VB.

I want to convert the array of string to array of int then sort the new array of in and display it in one line.

Example:
Input
2 4 1 2 5

Result: 1 2 2 4 5

I tried some solutions but didn't work

Here is my current code:

```
 Dim stringnum As String = "4 2 3"
    Dim result() As String = Split(stringnum, " ")

    Dim intList() As Integer

    intList = result.ConvertAll(Function(s) Integer.Parse(s))

    Console.WriteLine(Join(intList))
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: It didn't work means what? did you get an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
Console.WriteLine("Input your numbers :")

Dim stringnum = Console.ReadLine()
Dim result = Split(stringnum, " ")

Dim intList = Array.ConvertAll(result, Function(str) Integer.Parse(str))
Array.Sort(intList)

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", intList))
Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert the array of string to array of int then sort the new array of in and display it in one line.

Here it is mostly in one line using Linq

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Input your numbers :")
        Dim stringnum = Console.ReadLine()        
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", stringnum.Split(" ").Select(Function(str) Integer.Parse(str)).OrderBy(Function(x) x)))
    End Sub
End Module
```

After splitting the string `Split()` select each number from the array and parse them to integers `.Select(Function(str) Integer.Parse(str))`. That should provide the integers that can now be ordered `.OrderBy(Function(x) x)` and joined together to get the resulting output

Answer (score 0):

Despite what others say and think, you still can't beat the classic method for performance...

```
Dim stringnum As String = "4 2 3"
Dim result() As String = Split(stringnum, " ")
Dim intList(Ubound(result)) as integer 
For I as integer = 0 to ubound(result)
    Integer.TryParse(Result(i), intList(I))
Next
Array.Sort(intList)
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", intList))
```

I'm still genuinely of the opinion most of those shortcuts are just LAZY coding. Possibly with the exception of some of the sorting functions if you don't know how to do it right.